# Can I reference the type of an argument from a generic type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to add type-checking to the front-end of an api that I'm creating over web sockets. I've left out the complicated parts I don't believe are relevant to this question, but I can give more information if needed. I have a server listening on a web socket for messages formatted as `c|endpoint|command|data` as a string and will reply with the data requested. That part's working great, but I wanted to add type-checking to the client-side portion to help with debugging. Each endpoint has multiple commands, each taking their own custom data object that is stringified before sending it over, so each command must be a function that takes the socket and data and returns the data sent back.

```
interface Socket {
  send(data: string): void
}
interface Command<T> {
  (socket: Socket, data: T): string | Promise<string>
}
interface Endpoints {
  [index: string]: {
    [index: string]: Command<any>
  },
  test: {
    hello: Command<{testarg: string}>
  }
}
```

This example has one endpoint (`test`) with one command (`hello`) which takes data structured as `{testarg: string}`. Other commands will have different required data structures.

Now I have another function which sends the command from the client which is where I want the type-checking to happen.

```
class ClientSocket {
  // some parts not shown
  socket!: WebSocket

  call<T extends keyof Endpoints, K extends keyof Endpoints[T], U>(endpoint: T, command: K, data: U) {
    // call the api: this.socket.send(`c|${endpoint}|${command}|${JSON.stringify(data)}`) and save the promise resolve for later resolution when we get a reply. I left that out since it's not exactly relevant.
    return "promise for results of api call"
  }
}
```

I want call to take the three arguments, endpoint, command, and data as above, type-checked to the Endpoints interface so I get an error if I try to use it: `call("test", "hello", {})` because it's missing the `testarg` property. I figured out how to check the first two so I call a valid command, but I can't figure out how to type-check the data (U).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a little type wrapper that gets you the data type of the command in Endpoints[T][K]:

```
type CommandData<T extends keyof Endpoints, K extends keyof Endpoints[T]> = Endpoints[T][K] extends Command<infer TData> ? TData : never;
...
call<T extends keyof Endpoints, K extends keyof Endpoints[T]>(endpoint: T, command: K, data: CommandData<T, K>) {
        // call the api: this.socket.send(`c|${endpoint}|${command}|${JSON.stringify(data)}`) and save the promise resolve for later resolution when we get a reply. I left that out since it's not exactly relevant.
        return "promise for results of api call"
    }
...
new ClientSocket().call("test", "hello", { testarg: "hello" }); // { testarg: string } is expected
```

But you can shorten it to:

```
...
call<T extends keyof Endpoints, K extends keyof Endpoints[T]>(endpoint: T, command: K, data: Endpoints[T][K] extends Command<infer TData> ? TData : never) {
...
```

For more informations about the infer keyword see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html.

Comment: Ahh. I hadn't seen the infer keyword before. Thanks!